# Check date(mm/dd/yyyy) from database if it is less than current date

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007

What I'm trying here is to compare the dates. No Error is displayed when running this code , but at the same time, code does not fetch  any data from database too either.

The code is as shown below :

```
 string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Auto_Finance.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
        con.Open();
        string d1 = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
        DateTime df6 = DateTime.Now;
        int da1 = df6.Date.Month;
        int yr = df6.Date.Year;
        //DateTime df7 = new DateTime(df6.Year, df6.Month, df6.Day).AddYears(+1);
        //string sql = @"select * from ins where mon<=[@mon] and yr<=[@yr]";
        string sql = @"select * from ins where Insdate<=[@ddd]";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mon", da1);
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yr", yr);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ddd", d1);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        con.Close();
```

Any clarification and guidance is appreciated on what could be the cause of the issue here.

Comment: how is the date stored in your database? is it an actual date, or stored as a string? also, may be a silly question but are you positive that there are records that should be returned?

Comment: check what query is executing by putting break point...

Comment: Just wondering: is 'cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ddd", d1);' correct? I thought the '@' in the name should be omitted.

Comment: It's been a long time since I've last worked with ms-access, but as far as I remember there is a Format function you can use.

Comment: The parameter placeholder in your CommandText should not have square brackets around it. Try `... where Insdate<=@ddd`. Also, get rid of the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` as it is superfluous.